# Tomcat para de funcionar em um pc após um pequeno tempo

Tags: java, aplicação-web, tomcat

Então, tenho uma aplicação web (Java + Spring + JPA) no TomCat 9.0 e várias máquinas conectadas nele, celulares e notebooks, todos funcionando perfeitamente.

Porém, existe um notebook (i5, Windows 10 Pro) que conecta e consegue usar todas as funcionalidades, mas após 1 minuto mais ou menor ele fica sem resposta, ao atualizar a página o aviso é:

> 192.168.x.x(ip do servidor) não está funcionando.

Somente nesse notebook isso acontece, e o mais estranho é que ao retirar o domínio da aplicação consigo acessar o host do tomcat nesse notebook. Já desativei firewall e antivírus, mudei o ip e o navegador e nada, apenas ao reiniciar o note ele conecta, e logo cai.

Alguma ideia?

Comment: Tem log de erro ou warn?

Comment: Não, nada, os logs do Tomcat não mostram nada de errado, a aplicação não chega nem a carregar, percebi que no Mozilla o erro que  a página me mostra é Conexão reiniciada( A conexão para o servidor foi reiniciada durante o carregamento), e simultaneamente existem outros notebooks e celulares acessando sem problemas, inclusive após o notebook em questão parar de funcionar.

Comment: Já testou em outro navegador? Já tentou conectar esse notebook sem outro dispositivo estar conectado?

Comment: tente ficar disparando ping para esse servidor na maquina com problema quando para de funcionar, na teoria o ping deve parar também, pode ser também a placa de rede dessa maquina que não está funcionando bem, tente usar rede cabeada ou Wi-Fi e veja se o problema persiste

Comment: Isso aí pode ser qualquer coisa que leve o programa à exaustão. Talvez pouca memória (o programa dura mais de 1 minuto se não for usado)? Pode ser um processe em segundo plano consumindo recursos. Pode ser um timeout com a conexão do banco de dados que não é mais reaberta (bancos de dados locais com a configuração padrão podem apresentar limites surpreendentemente pequenos). Pode ser um deadlock de qualquer natureza que segura as demais conexões. Pode ser que o sistema não esteja fechando as conexões com o banco e o pool de conexões esteja vazia, o que bloqueia as novas requisições.

Comment: Sugiro tentar criar alguma página mais simples, sem acesso ao banco, e ver se ela continua acessível. Enfim, realize alguns testes tentando isolar o problema e determinar se é mesmo no tomcat ou em alguma função específica do sistema. Monitorar a JVM usando uma ferramenta como JVisualVM que vem no JDK 6 em diante pode ajudar bastante. A ferramenta permite ver em tempo real a memória usada, as threads ativas (e possíveis deadlocks, se souber analisar as pilhas) e muito mais.